# AzureDataFactory how to store output of Filter action

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am using Filter action in pipeline on Json from blob file. How to store filter output to blob/any storage?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you mean filter activity, please check this doc. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-filter-activity#type-properties